# I keep getting the error sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

#I've just started python and I'm looking into creating a login system using sql. My code is as follows:

```
def Register(iduser):
    people=[]
    Usern=input('Enter a Username: ')
    Passw=input('Enter a Password: ')
    people.append(iduser)
    people.append(Usern)
    people.append(Passw)
    with sqlite3.connect('Users.db') as db:
       cursor=db.cursor()
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Users VALUES (?,?,?)", people)
       db.commit()
```

#As said in the title, I keep getting error sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. I don't know much about python, so when I look at other questions i get confused, is there a solution to this that I may be able to understand?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide the full error message, including traceback? Thanks!

Comment: 1) share the  'CREATE TABLE' 2) print the type of each entry in people. Example: `print(type(people[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

The 'people' variable is a list. You should convert it into a tuple in order to insert the data into your 'Users' table.